# asp.net C# accessing a unc shared folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, unc

I have a webserver and a file cluster which i need to access.
I can map the file cluster no problem
however when I try to save files to the unc drive i only get errors.
in my web config I have the following;

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Docs" value="\\xxxxxx-filecluster\fileshare\" />
  </appSettings>

<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

in the code I have :-

```
    void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        // Specify the path to save the uploaded file to.
        string savePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Docs"];
```

on the managed server I have a local account called fileuser and on the domain i have another user called dom/fileuser.

In IIS i have an application pool running under dom/filesuer, however still cannot save any file to the unc drive.

```
 Access to the path '\\xxxxxx-filecluster\fileshare\test.txt' is denied.
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does savePath return when you debug? Idk if that's a typo but you need to access with \\ to a UNC path. In your config it's only \

Comment: Hi It was a typo - I have updated the quesiton (thanks) though it does come back with \\xxxxxx-filecluster\fileshare\

Comment: Well, you might need to provide Read access to the account you use (IIS_USRS or the account you "impersonate") for the shared folder.

Comment: What is the identity used by the appdomain of your website? Are these servers domain joined? Are you using a domain account?

Answer (score 0):

Already commented but here we go:

I think the issue is related with privileges of the accounts that you use to access the file.

If your config is like:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="foo" password="bar"/>
```

The user `foo` needs to have at least `Read` privilege on the shared folder.

Comment: Hi i have tried this but I get The user name or password is incorrect.,  which i dont understand because when I map a network drive using the exact same credentials - it does work. (this is using the domain user) - and site is running under the app pool with these credentials.

Comment: Well, it sounds like we could actually fix the initial issue. You can now access the UNC path.
As for credentials, in the config you should be using DOMAIN\username just in case you dont.

Comment: unfortunatly still giving me an error saying that the The user name or password is incorrect.-